# Differing scrambling parameter generation methods in Secure Remote Protocol

Tags: cryptography, key-exchange

[RFC 2945](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2945) (The SRP Authentication and Key Exchange System) states,

> The parameter u is a 32-bit unsigned integer which takes its value from the first 32 bits of the SHA1 hash of B, MSB first.

whereas [the original publication](http://srp.stanford.edu/ndss.html#SECTION00032200000000000000) describing SRP states that u is random.

What benefit is gained from using bits from a hash of B and restricting the size, rather than straight pseudorandom data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original article also states that: "For example, both sides can compute *u* as a simple function of *B*", which is what occurs in RFC 2945. *u* could be generated randomly and also transmitted, but deriving *u* from *B* (which is already transmitted) is harmless (security wise) and saves a few bytes (which is always good).